# pnotify not working in my symfony 4 and webpack using yarn

Tags: webpack, yarnpkg, pnotify

I'm using symfony 4.2; I'm also using webpack and yarn to manage my assets.
I have added the package using:

```bash
yarn add pnotify
```

I can see the files in `node_modules`. I have required both the css and the js files:

```js
require('pnotify/dist/PNotifyBrightTheme.css');
require('pnotify');
```

When I run this command I get the error below:

```js
yarn run encore dev
```

> Can't resolve pnotify in app.js

If I change the `require` to this it builds successfully:

```js
require('pnotify/dist/umd/PNotify');
```

When I try to test with twig like this, I get the error below:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    (new PNotify({
      title: 'Regular Notice,
      text: 'Check me out! I\'m a notice.',
      type: 'info',
      styling: 'bootstrap3'
    }));
  });
</script>
```

```
> vendor.js:7803 Uncaught ReferenceError: PNotify is not defined
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (create:513)
at mightThrow (vendor.js:7510)
at process (vendor.js:7578)
```

Comment: Try `import Pnotify from 'pnotify/dist/umd/PNotify'`

Comment: @@mblaettermann i already did that in the second section of my question and i get the error above

Comment: `import PNotify from 'pnotify';`

Ensure required globals are available
`window.PNotify = PNotify;`

Comment: ok let me try that

Comment: @mblaettermann It didn't work for me

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the correct way is this:

```
import PNotify from 'pnotify/dist/es/PNotify';
import PNotifyButtons from 'pnotify/dist/es/PNotifyButtons';
```

[As per this link](https://github.com/sciactive/pnotify/blob/master/README.md#react)